# <li> mis-alignment depending on text

Tags: css

I am trying to have a horiztonal li elements create these card effects.

However, it seems that the amount of text inside of them is throwing their alignment off (some higher than other). For example, the 3rd box has more text than the other 2 so it's placed higher than the others.

```
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 282px;
  height: 368px;
  background: url("../img/comedians/comedian-card.png");
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

How can I make them align irrespective of the text inside?

http://f.cl.ly/items/2e2I2Z0x0g3M2D1o2F0t/stackoverflow.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align`, eg: `vertical-align: middle`. I'll try to come up with a demo in a second.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wMb8t/1/

### CSS

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your blocks are `inline-block`, you should add `vertical-align:top;`